CORS Error When Fetching Extensions in VS Code ,Failed to fetch
I'm encountering a CORS error when trying to search for and install extensions in Visual Studio Code.
enter image description here
The Developer Tools console shows the following error:
enter image description here
Access to fetch at 'https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/extensionquery' from origin 'vscode-file://vscode-app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
I have tried the following without success:

Checked proxy settings.

Tried using a different network (with and without VPN).

Verified that VS Code is updated to the latest version.


Any help would be appreciated!

Check VS Code Settings: Ensure that the following settings are set to default in your settings.json file. (You can access this file by pressing Ctrl + ,)
"http.proxy": "",
"https.proxy": "",
"http.proxyStrictSSL": true


{
"http.proxy": "",
"https.proxy": "",
"http.proxyStrictSSL": true
}
I added these settings here:
C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json
but nothing changed.
